# IOS UI Testing - Waiting for the network calls

Tags: ios, xctest, ios-ui-automation, xctestcase

I am writing a test cases for IOS using the XCTest framework. How can we wait for a network call and start our execution once our network call is finished.
Currently, I am using sleep() for waiting. But, its not the best way to do it as it.
So, is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 3):

Read documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/asynchronous_tests_and_expectations/testing_asynchronous_operations_with_expectations).

```
func testDownloadWebData() {
    // Create an expectation for a background download task.
    let expectation = XCTestExpectation(description: "Download apple.com home page")

    // Create a URL for a web page to be downloaded.
    let url = URL(string: "https://apple.com")!

    // Create a background task to download the web page.
    let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, _, _) in

        // Make sure we downloaded some data.
        XCTAssertNotNil(data, "No data was downloaded.")

        // Fulfill the expectation to indicate that the background task has finished successfully.
        expectation.fulfill()

    }

    // Start the download task.
    dataTask.resume()

    // Wait until the expectation is fulfilled, with a timeout of 10 seconds.
    wait(for: [expectation], timeout: 10.0)
}
```

Comment: How to get it worked for UI Testing, as UI Testing is to be done without considering the internal code and api urls.
Is the above solution applicable for UI Test cases.
If not, is there any other way?

Comment: To wait for a UI element to appear, you would use `func expectation(for predicate: NSPredicate, evaluatedWith object: Any, handler: XCTNSPredicateExpectation.Handler? = nil) -> XCTestExpectation`, which returns an expectation that would be waited for as in the above sample code.

Comment: Yes! Correct. But the question is, how to detect that  the loader is started or stopped. Your help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance